# Other libraries that aren't mip or gurobi or scipy to solve optimization problem

Tags: python, optimization, minimization

I would like to find the best python library to solve the below problem.

[image]

I don't want to use gurobi because it can't be downloaded onto the board that will be running the code. I tried using MIP but it won't solve non-linear functions. I am trying to use scipy now but am having a lot of trouble defining the constraints. My question is are there other libraries like MIP or Gurobi that are easy to declare variables and constraints in. Thank you for any help or advice!!

Comment: You seem to say `-1.5 ≤ x[i] ≤ 1.5` but also `x[i] is integer`. That looks strange or sloppy. Better is `-1 ≤ x[i] ≤ 1`. Furthermore, the objective is nonsensical (what is i?). It would be good to clean up your mathematical model before asking about solvers.

Comment: Thanks for the advice!!

Comment: This looks like a MIQP model. Most MIQP solvers use large, complex algorithms. Usually not suited for small embedded systems. Maybe [miosqp](https://github.com/oxfordcontrol/miosqp) is something for you to look at.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion!!